# SQL - 1 Parent Table, 2 Child Tables - return single row for each row in the child table

Tags: sql, join, union

**Table A**

- ParentID
- Name

**Table B**

- BKey
- ParentID
- DescB

**Table C**

- CKey
- ParentID
- DescC

I need to return 1 row for each combined row of data in B/A that match the parent id and if one of the child tables has more rows than the other, a row should be returned with nulls for that description.

For example, if the data was as following

**Table A**

```
1   FirstParent
2   Second Parent
```

**Table B**

```
1   1   BDesc1
2   1   BDesc2
3   2   P2BDesc1
```

**Table C**

```
1   1   CDesc1
2   2   P2CDesc1
3   2   P2CDesc2
```

If I retrieve based on `FirstParent`, the results should be:

```
1   FirstParent   BDesc1   CDesc1
1   FirstParent   BDesc2   NULL
```

If I retrieve based on `SecondParent`, the results should be:

```
2   SecondParent   P2BDesc1   P2CDesc1
2   SecondParent   NULL       P2CDesc2
```

Is there anyway of doing this without having to unions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @ParentID int
set @ParentID = 1

select a.name,
       bc.descb,
       bc.descc
from   TableA as a
  cross join (select b.descb,
                     c.descc
              from   (select *,
                             row_number() over(order by b.bkey) as rn
                      from   TableB as b
                      where  b.parentid = @parentid) as b
                full outer join 
                     (select *,
                             row_number() over(order by c.ckey) as rn
                      from   TableC as c
                      where  c.parentid = @parentid) as c
                  on b.rn = c.rn) as bc
where  a.parentid = @parentid
```

Try here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/qt/112538/

**Edit:** A version using ExternalKey to query multiple ParentID's

Suggested indexes:

```
create index IX_B_ParentID on TableB(ParentID) include (DescB)
create index IX_C_ParentID on TableC(ParentID) include (DescC)
```

I would create a table variable that holds the ParentID's that matches the ExternalKey and then use that instead of TableA in the query.

```
declare @ExternalKey int = 1

declare @T table(ParentID int primary key, Name varchar(20))
insert into @T (ParentID, Name)
select ParentID, NAme
from TableA
where ExternalKey = @ExternalKey


select a.name,
       bc.descb,
       bc.descc
from   @T as a
  inner join (select b.descb,
                     c.descc,
                     coalesce(b.ParentID, c.ParentID) as ParentID
              from   (select b.ParentID,
                             b.DescB,
                             row_number() over(partition by b.ParentID order by b.bkey) as rn
                      from   TableB as b
                      where  b.parentid in (select ParentID from @T)) as b
                full outer join
                     (select c.ParentID,
                             c.DescC,
                             row_number() over(partition by c.ParentID order by c.ckey) as rn
                      from   TableC as c
                      where  c.parentid in (select ParentID from @T)) as c
                  on b.rn = c.rn and
                     b.ParentID = c.ParentID) as bc
    on a.ParentID = bc.ParentID
```

Comment: We have a different way of understanding the question, your solution is perfectly valid. +1. I assumed the whole result should be combined without using a union. But it could also be the subresult the OP wanted for each A.parentID to be retrieved without a union.

Comment: This answers the question as I asked it.  So, I will mark it answered.  However, I did simplify it a bit.  Additionally on the parent table a is a column ExternalKey and i would typically pull by the external key so it must retrieve the resultset with more than one parentid based on the externalkey and i am having problems referencing the parentid from table a while changing your example.

Comment: @leifre - It would be easier to modify the answer provided by @t-clausen.dk to fit your requirement. Just add a where clause to the main query. `where a.ExternalKey = SomeValue`.

Comment: its more like: Table A - ParentID, Name, ExternalKeyID   And then i would put the externalkeyid in a where clause

Comment: @leifre - Yes :) I edited my comment to that. You obviously saw my first version.

Comment: then my only concen is the CTEs dont limit their resultset...would it pull the whole table for b and c expressions...the table can be quite large

Comment: @leifre - Yes. That is a valid concern. I assume you have indexes on `ParentID`in table B and C? If that is the case, the query plan for my version is shows that it is better to limit the rows in the sub queries. I will try to add a modified version of my query that uses externalid from table A.

Comment: yes there are indexes on those columns.  A little bit in depth about CTEs...is a question of when they are executed...would the query optimizer put it all together on the join and limit the resultset...or will it pull the whole table and then join the resultset (which would not be a good thing)

Comment: From the query plan I get, with not much data, it looks like the row_number() is executed for the entire TableB and TableC in the CTE version. That is not a good thing because it will of course use a table scan. So it looks a lot better if you can reduce the number of rows already in the inner query. I have updated my answer. Note: I do not know what the query plan would look like if there are a lot of data in the tables. The plan might change.

Answer (score 2):

I truely hope this is MSSQL question

```
declare @a table(
ParentID int,
Name varchar(15))

declare @b table(
BKey int,
ParentID int, 
DescB varchar(10))


declare @c table(
CKey int,
ParentID int,
DescC varchar(10))

insert @a values (1,'FirstParent')
insert @a values (2,'SecondParent')

insert @b values(1, 1, 'BDesc1')
insert @b values(2, 1, 'BDesc2')
insert @b values(3, 2, 'P2BDesc1') 

insert @c values(1, 1, 'CDesc1')
insert @c values(2, 2, 'P2CDesc1')
insert @c values(3, 2, 'P2CDesc2')

;with b as
(
    select DescB, ParentID, row_number() over (partition by parentid order by DescB) rn from @b
),
c as
(
    select DescC, ParentID, row_number() over (partition by parentid order by DescC) rn from @c
), 
d as (
    select DescB, DescC, coalesce(b.parentid, c.parentid) parentid from b
    full outer join c
    on c.parentid = b.parentid and c.rn = b.rn
)
select a.ParentID, a.Name, d.DescB, d.DescC from @a a
join d
on a.parentid = d.parentid
order by 1
```

Try here:
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/112537/

Comment: Otroligt :) This is just to much. Equal right down to the  "Try here" link. +1. 49 sec after you.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson sorry about that, I will buy you a beer next time you are in Denmark.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it in 2 steps:

1) Calculate number of records in every child tables.

2) Join 1st or 2nd table regarding to number of records from 1st step

```
select a.ParentId, a.Name, b.DescB, c.DescC
from (
    select ParentId, (select count(*) from b where a.ParentId = b.ParentId) as cntB,
    (select count(*) from c where a.ParentId = b.ParentId) as cntC
from a
left join b cntB >= cntC and a.ParentId = b.ParentId
left join c cntB < cntC and a.ParentId = c.ParentId
```

Comment: I tried to make this work, but gave up after several incorrect syntax.

Comment: interesting idea though, wouldnt have thought to take this approach